# substituting spherical coordinates to evaluate an integral.

Tags: multivariable-calculus, spherical-coordinates

I have to evaluate

$$\int^1_{-1} \int^{ \sqrt {1-x^2}}_{-\sqrt {1-x^2}} \int^1_{-\sqrt{x^2+y^2}} \, dz \, dy \, dx$$

using spherical coordinates.

This is what I have come up with

\begin{align}
& \int^1_0 \int^{2\pi}_0 \int^{3\pi/4}_0 r^2\sin\theta \, d\theta \, d\phi \, dr \\[10pt]
= {} & \int^1_0 r^2 \, dr \int^{2\pi}_0 d \phi \int^{3\pi/4}_0 r^2\sin\theta \, d\theta \\[10pt]
= {} & \frac 1 3 \times 2\pi \times \left[-\cos\theta\vphantom{\frac 1 1}\right]^{3\pi/4}_0
\end{align}

by a combination of sketching and substituting spherical coordinates.

After evaluating I obtain this integral to equal 3.57.

where as the first one evaluates to 5.236.

EDIT:
A bit of thought shows me that the above integral gives a spherical volume. We need to restrict $r$

As $x^2 + y^2 = 1 \implies \rho = \csc \theta$

$$\int^{3\pi/4}_{\pi/4} \int^{2\pi}_0 \int^{\csc \theta}_1 r^2\sin\theta \, dr d\phi \, d\theta $$

However

This, yet again, does not give me what I want.

Comment: Can you describe geometrically what the (first) region is supposed to be? That might help us tell you where you went awry...

Comment: The region $0 \leq z \leq -\sqrt{x^2 + y^2}$ ? That is a cone with maximum at the origin.  the remaining two describe a disk. at the origin with radius 1.

Comment: Unless I am screwing it up - cough - is it not the region bounded by a cylinder of radius 1 ($x^2 +y^2 =1 $), by $z=1$ on the top, and by the cone $z=-\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$ on the bottom? So I would have been inclined to do this in cylindrical coordinates... Not allowed? Also - just to get every thing down: what are your $\phi$ and $\theta$? For me - usually! -$\theta$ is the counter-clockwise angle from the $x$ axis (in the $x/y$ plane), and $\phi$ the downwards angle from the $z$ axis: the volume element is then $\rho^2 \sin \phi \,d\phi\,d\theta\,d\rho$ - which is not what you have.

Comment: My sketch totally agrees with you, but he asked for spherical. I have $\theta $ as the angle from the downward z-axis. and $\phi$ in the x,y plane. although in my question I do have them the wrong way around. I will edit now. In my calculations I had it the correct way around.

Comment: So - first of all I suggest that you do this first in cylindrical, as a sanity test - regardless of the asked question.... So - assuming $\theta =0$ points south - the maximum $\rho$ - my notation -must depend on $\theta$ - correct? It is not $1$ always...  For instance, if $\theta = \pi/4$, $\rho$ can be as large as $\sqrt 2$. You will need two formulas for $\rho$-maximum, because the constraints on the top and the cylinder sides are different.

Comment: you wrote below - "I never thought of switching to polar coordinates" - that is cylindrical coordinates = "z + polar"! Fare thee well, spherical?

Comment: I am working on it. I can see what I have gives me a sphere. so I need to "restrict" $r$

Comment: OK - I have to run... But again, just to make sure we agree on notation: $\rho$ is the distance from the origin in $3$-space - usually $r$ is the distance in the $x/y$ plane (i.,e. projection of $\rho$ onto the$x/y$ plane)... The maximum $\rho$ attains, as one walks in a straight line away from the origin, depends on the line, i.e., on (your) $\theta$.

Comment: I have updated, that's all I can do. I had to change the range on $\theta$ otherwise we would be dividing by zero in the calculations. I have spent all day on this, so have given up. I will be opening a bounty whenever I can. I am beat.

Comment: I'll give it a whirl later on... sleep tight! BTW, to calculate the volume, you could have taken that of the whole cylindre, calculated by base times height, and  subtract the vol of the cone, the latter calculated 'spherically'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To compare various answers:
As described in the comments, the region is a enclosed by the cylinder $x^2+y^2 = 1$, with top $z=1$, and bottom the cone $z=-\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$.

Sol 1:
The region has volume $V$ = that of a cylinder minus the cone, i.e.,
$$ V = 2 \pi 1^2 - 1/3 \cdot \pi 1^2 \cdot 1 = 5 \pi/3.$$
(The volume of the cone can most easily be done by Pappus's theorem, aka, looking it up, or by the disc method of integration.)

Sol 2: Using cylindrical coordinates - as in Michael Hardy's solution:
$$V = \int_{\phi=0}^{2\pi}\int_{r=0}^1\int_{z=-r}^1\, dz\, r dr \, d\theta = 2\pi \int_{r=0}^{1}(1+r)r\,dr= 2\pi\left(1/2 + 1/3\right). $$

Sol 3: Using spherical coordinates, as desired.

Notation: if I have understood the comments correctly:

- $\phi$ sweeps counter-clockwise in the $x/y$ plane, starting from the $x$-axis,
- $\theta$ sweeps upwards from the $z$-axis, so that $\theta=0$ corresponds to due South;
- $\rho$ is the distance from the origin.

Then the volume element $dV = \rho^2 \sin \theta \, d\theta \, d\phi\, d\rho$.

Walking on a line from the origin (i.e., holding $\theta$ and $\phi$ fixed), we start at $\rho=0$, but eventually encounter the boundary of the region.

- If $\pi/4 \le \theta \le 3\pi/ 4$, the line encounters the exterior of the cylinder ($x^2+y^2 =1 $); call this region $R_1$ - here $$\rho_{\rm max} = \csc \theta,$$
  as you have it in your edit above.
- If $3\pi/4 \le \theta \le \pi $, the line encounters the top disk, where $z= 1$; call this region $R_2$ - here $$\rho_{\rm max } = -\sec \theta,$$
  the negative sign because $\cos \theta$ is negative in this region, with this (unusual?) convention for $\theta$...

Calculate $V = V_1 + V_2$:

- $V_1$:
  $$\begin{align} V_1 &= \int \int \int_{R_1} \,dV = \int_{\phi=0}^{2\pi} \int_{\theta = \pi/4}^{3\pi/4}\int_{\rho=0}^{\csc \theta} \rho^2 \,d\rho\, \sin \theta \, d\theta \,d\phi \\
  &= 2 \pi \int_{\theta =\pi/4}^{3\pi/4} 1/3 \csc^3\theta \sin \theta \, d\theta \\
  & ={2\pi\over 3} \int_{\theta =\pi/4}^{3\pi/4}\csc^2\theta \,d\theta \\
  & ={2\pi\over 3}( -\cot \theta )\mid_{\pi/4}^{3\pi/4} \\
  &={4 \pi \over 3}.\\
  \end{align}$$
- $V_2$:
  $$\begin{align} V_2 &= \int \int \int_{R_2} \,dV = \int_{\phi=0}^{2\pi} \int_{\theta = 3\pi/4}^{\pi}\int_{\rho=0}^{-\sec \theta} \rho^2 \,d\rho\, \sin \theta \, d\theta \,d\phi \\
  &= 2 \pi \int_{\theta =3\pi/4}^{\pi} (-1/3) \cos^{-3}\theta \sin \theta \, d\theta \\
  & =-{2\pi}\cdot{1/6}\, \cos^{-2}\theta \,\mid_{3\pi/4}^{\pi} \\
  &={ \pi \over 3}.\\
  \end{align}$$

So $V= 5\pi/3$.

I hope I didn't mess anything up... In any case, spherical coordinates are perhaps not the best choice for this problem - right?

*Note:* I'm not sure I got your convention for $\theta$ correctly... In any case, why don't you calculate the volume of the cone using spherical coordinates? - it has to come out to $\pi/3$... If you are still confused, probably you should do the problem 'live' in front of your instructor...

Comment: I can not thank you enough peter. I have decided to stick with a more conventional, like you suggest, way to define $\theta$ So with the bounds of $\theta $ for $R_2$ we obtain. $0 \leq \theta \leq \pi/2$ and so the upper bound on $\rho$ is $sec \theta$. I can not thank you enough. THANKS

Comment: I mean $ \pi/4$... sorry.

Comment: I think where you have $\cos^2 \theta$ you should have $\frac{\tan ^2 \theta}{2}$ n the calculations for V_2

Comment: No - "u" substitution: $u= \cos \theta$, $du = - \sin \theta \,d\theta$, so we are basically doing $\int u^{-3}\, du$

Comment: Oh, I see, your way should work too.

Comment: And just to be clear - I had $\cos^{-2}$, not $\cos^2$...

Comment: To belabor, or belabour, the point $\cos^{-2} = \sec^2$, and $1 + \tan^2 =\sec^2$, so your version and mine differ by a constant - the " + c" of anti-dfferentiation, so all is well. And - I should have said earlier, thanks for the thanks...

Answer (score 1):

$$
\int^1_{-\sqrt{x^2+y^2}} \, dz = 1+\sqrt{x^2+y^2}.
$$
Therefore
\begin{align}
& \int^1_{-1} \int^{ \sqrt {1-x^2}}_{-\sqrt {1-x^2}} \int^1_{-\sqrt{x^2+y^2}} \, dz \, dy \, dx = \int^1_{-1} \int^{ \sqrt {1-x^2}}_{-\sqrt {1-x^2}}  \left(1+\sqrt{x^2+y^2}\,\right) \,dy\,dx \\[20pt]
& \text{Now switch to polar coordinates:} \\[10pt]
= {} & \underbrace{\int_0^{2\pi} \quad \overbrace{\int_0^1 (1+r)\, r\,dr}^\text{No “$\,\theta\,$'' appears here.} \quad d\theta = 2\pi \int_0^1 (1+r)\, r\,dr}_\text{These are equal because “$\,\theta\,$'' does not appear in the inside integral.} = \cdots \cdots
\end{align}

Comment: I have never thought of switching to polar coordinates after integrating.